# isinstance with docx.Document class

Tags: python, isinstance

in a script I want to run certain lines when a variable is of type Document. However this check always returns false, no matter the input.

```
from docx import Document
from docx import Document as _Document

document = Document('use_this_doc.docx') 
isinstance (document, _Document)
```

`type(document)` returns `docx.document.Document`

`isinstance(document, _Document)`  returns `False`, while I would expect it to return `True`. `isinstance(document, type(Document))` also returns `False`.

How can I adjust the code for it to return True in the case as specified?

Comment: What do you get from `isinstance(document, Document)`?

Answer (score 4):

`Document()` is a helper function (not a `class`) to open a document. The developer didn't follow [PEP8 naming conventions](https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/#naming-conventions) and used a class like naming for a function. It returns an object of type `docx.document.Document`.

> *docx.Document* (a function) is not the same as *docx.document.Document* (a type).

Calling `isinstance(document, Document)` would generate an error because the second argument must be a type.

```
import docx
from docx import Document

print("docx.Document =>", type(docx.Document))
print("docx.document.Document =>", type(docx.document.Document))

document = Document('use_this_doc.docx') 

print(type(document), isinstance(document, docx.document.Document))
```

**Output:**

```
docx.Document => <class 'function'>
docx.document.Document => <class 'type'>

<class 'docx.document.Document'> True
```